# Interception of ViewModels in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, unity-container, aop

I have a lot of ViewModels in an App and most of them are declared and referenced as Static Resources in the XAML of the Views. Now I need to implement some comprehensive logging of ViewModel invocations and was hoping to use some form of interception e.g. with Unity; but it appears I'd need to substitute, i.e. wrap or inherit ("instance" or "type") in Unity and basically create a proxy imperatively/dynamically in code which seems to rule out declaring the ViewModel class in the XAML. So are there any workarounds toward using interception and keeping declarative ViewModels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare your view models in XAML Unity is not in control of object instantiation. That means the container does not have the chance to wrap your vm with a proxy/interceptor.

[Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) offers the concept of a View/ViewModelLocator that connects view and vm automatically. You can use it in combination with Unity to create your vm's. That should enable you to intercept and trace invocations.